# On a degenerate SDE in the unit ball

Tags: stochastic-processes, dirichlet-forms

This is a question about a diffusion process on the unit ball.

In this article [J.S](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304414901001405?token=174B17FEF2BDB149FBF587F58D5D81B07C0A213DCA2898A008BB6C2356E8DA7D485A0CF4F8CB33D6A71D7A7CE5128ADB), the author considered the following SDE in the **closed** unit ball $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad dX_t=\sqrt{2(1-|X_t|^2)}\,dB_t-cX_t\,dt,
\end{align*}
where $\{B_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ is an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion, $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c$ is a nonnegative constant. We define an elliptic operator $(\mathcal{A},\text{Dom}(\mathcal{A}))$ by $\mathcal{A}=C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)|_E$  and
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}f=(1-|x|^2)\Delta f-c x\cdot \nabla f,\quad f \in \text{Dom}(\mathcal{A}).
\end{align*}
Then, standard results from martingale problems show that there exists a diffusion process $\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ on $E$ such that
$f(X_t)-f(x)-\int_{0}^{t}\mathcal{A}f(X_s)\,ds \quad(t \ge 0,\, x \in E)
$
is a martingale. Thus, the SDE $(1)$ possesses a solution. Furthermore, we can show that the solution is unique in the sense of distribution (by the way, the pathwise uniqueness for (1) is a very profound problem).

**My question is as follows.**

If $c=0$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is a weighted Laplacian on $E$ and the corresponding diffusion process $X$ is a time-changed absorbing Brownian motion on the interior of $E$. The boundary $\partial E$ is the cemetery of $X$. If $c>0$, the corresponding  diffusion process is a time-changed standard Brownian motion with drift?

Thank you in advance.

As for the above question, I may solved it myself.

Comment: I think $\mathcal{A} f = (1-|x|^2) \nabla f - c x \cdot \nabla f$.  Also, transforming to polar coordinates may shed insight into your questions.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you. $\mathcal{A}$ should be defined as you pointed out.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I am rather at a loss in interpreting boundary conditions. Even if $c$ vanishes, the corresponding diffusion process is not a time changed reflected B.M., right?.

Comment: Clearly, if $c=0$, then the SDE has a fixed point on the unit sphere.  That corresponds to an absorbed B.M., i.e., after the boundary is hit, the process will never leave the boundary for all subsequent times.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I see. I asked a strange question. So, the solution to (1) is identified with a time-changed Brownian motion with drift?

Comment: It seems there is a slight transcription error in (1): the paper you mention considers an SDE with a quadratic diffusion coefficient.  As the paper indicates, the classification of the boundary depends on $c$: if $c=0$ the process is a time-changed absorbed Brownian motion; if $0<c<2$, the process hits the boundary infinitely often and the solution can be identified with a time-changed reflecting Brownian motion with drift; and if $c \ge 2$, the process never reaches the boundary and can be identified with a time-changed Brownian motion with drift.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I think (1) is correct as it is. (1) is interesting in that the diffusion coefficients is not Lipschitz continuous. The pathwise uniqueness for (1) holds if $c \ge 2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. If $c<2(\sqrt{2}-1)$, the uniqueness remains unknown.

Comment: Yes, you are right, (1) is correct.    The html version of the paper did not display the square root for some reason.